# JAVA - Changing method return type from void to String instantly creates 'dead' code?

Tags: java, variables, types, return, global

I wrote a class a while back, which gets a specific set of values from specific XML files. It can then print the results in Console and it works just fine.
But of course I didn't make a class to print to console

I need to get the values into a database. There is a separate class that handles the db input.

But I am having great trouble getting the local variables from the method that loops the XML files returned/passed to the database class.

I cannot get the values from inside the main method that reads them from the XML files (the values from the Nodelist 'nodes'). I tried using a bunch of global variables, but they don't get updated. I read that using 'global variables' was the way to go, but I also read (and found out when coding), that JAVA makes a copy from the actual bits inside the object and works with that inside a method. So when the method ends all the alterations made to variables are ignored and the value of the object is the same as it was before the method ran.

Here is the code that gives the problem:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class xmlGrabber {
public static String NAME = "StartNaam"; // declare the global variable


  public String main(String[] args) 
   throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, 
          IOException, XPathExpressionException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    String docuInvoer = "C:/temp/document.xml";
    Document doc = builder.parse(docuInvoer);
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
       // XPath Query for showing all nodes value
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//@fieldvalue");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 1; i < 24; i++) {
    // System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
     //String bla = nodes.item(1).getNodeValue(); 
    String NAME = nodes.item(1).getNodeValue(); //Modify value of NAME

    } return NAME;
  }
//  public static String NAME(){
    //  System.out.println(NAME+"test");
    //  return NAME;        
    //  }
}
```

When trying to read the variable in a different class like so:

```
public class Debug {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     xmlGrabber.main(null);
     String name = xmlGrabber.NAME;
     System.out.println(name); 
 }
}
```

The IDE throws the error: NAME cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: "JAVA makes a copy from the actual bits inside the object and works with that inside a method. So when the method ends all the alterations made to variables are ignored and the value of the object is the same as it was before the method ran." Where did you read that? If I understand what you're talking about, it should be the *opposite* of that. Typically, changes made to object inside a method will stick around after the method returns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: @Menno: That question actually confirms my suspicion (see the second example on the top-voted answer). I believe you are mis-interpreting the first example.

Comment: Java doesn't make a copy of the bits inside an object, it just copies the _value_ of the _reference_ to each `Object` argument to the method. If you change that new _reference_ (by assigning a different `Object` to the parameter) that doesn't affect the caller, which is still referencing the original object. Mutating the internal state of an object, however, does.

Comment: @Adam: I guess I might be mistaken, but I have read a few other sites on the subject. I will read some more about it asap.

Comment: @Menno: Could you post the *exact* version of the code that causes the "dead code" error?

Comment: @Menno: Your latest version of the code compiles correctly for me... Are you sure you're compiling the code that you pasted here?

Comment: @Adam, it compiles no problem indeed. But when I read the variable NAME in a different class it gives "StartNaamtest" as result. Not the value that is gained from the XML, but the inital value

Comment: @Menno: I think we're starting to get somewhere... So, you have *another* class that reads `NAME`, correct? In that *other* class, try calling `xmlGrabber.main(null);` *before* reading `NAME`.

Comment: @Menno: When you run a Java program, only **one** class's `main` method is automatically invoked for you. They won't all magically start running at the same time. When you ran the *other* class's `main` method, `xmlGrabber`'s main method was ignored until *you* manually invoked it using `xmlGrabber,main(null)`.

Comment: Oops. I said it worked, but it didn't. I was looking at the wrong class. I've made changes to both classes, so it now has the line " String name = xmlGrabber.main(null);" before reading name.

Comment: @Menno: Get rid of the `String name =` part. **Just** write `xmlGrabber.main(null);`. **After** that, write `String name = xmlGrabber.NAME;`.

Comment: @Adam. First; thanks a lot for your continued help!! I tried doing that, Adam, but unfortunately the value the second class prints out is still the initial value of "Startnaam". To test what was happening I tried commenting  out the global variable initialisation : //public static String NAME = "StartNaam";. This resulted in an error in the second class: NAME cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: I updated the code in the initial question to the latest versions

Comment: @Menno: Try using this code for the `xmlGrabber` class: http://pastebin.com/yGzEiKqf . In the *other* class, all you should have to write is `String name = xmlGrabber.readXmlFile();`

Comment: @Adam. Hi Adam, I tried it (just renamed the code you gave me to xmlGrabber2 so I could compare the two versions). Unfortunately Eclipse throws: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at laadpackage.xmlGrabber2.readXmlFile(xmlGrabber2.java:36)
 at laadpackage.dbput.main(dbput.java:25)

(dbput is the second class (that puts the values into the database))
Both errors refer to the lines with the name variable in it:
String name = xmlGrabber2.readXmlFile(); (dbput)
name = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue(); // Modify value of NAME (xmlGrabber2)

Comment: @Adam. Allright! This time I verified it, and the xml's value does get saved into the database! I made this alteration:
name = nodes.item(1).getNodeValue(); // "1" used to be "i"
I am over the moon with joy! Thanks so much for all the feedback!!! How do I give you credit for answering the question? ;)

Comment: @Menno: Well, I technically did not answer your original question. Rightfully, it should have been divided up into a different question once you realized that the original question no longer applied. Don't worry about giving credit.

Answer (score 4):

When the compiler checks for dead code, it makes an exception for a main method with the signature

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

because the point of the main method is it is an entry point, something that you can call from the command line or from a script or something and kick things off.

When you change the return type then it doesn't match that signature, it's no longer a valid main method, just some method that nowhere else in the program calls: dead code.

Also, when your main method stops running the program goes away. For you to save the results of your xml parsing to a database either you should make calls from your xml parsing code to the data access class (alternatively you could write the results to stdout and pipe them to a separate java program that reads data from stdin and saves it to the database).

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. So the warning is always there, but hidden by default if it is for that specific method?

Comment: @Nathan: But why is `i++` considered dead code in the first place? I would have expected the compiler to instead complain about the lack of a return statement.

Comment: @Adam: I don't know why it complains about that exact statement. I have a work in progress version with return statements for NAME in the main method, but it still gives the second class the initial value of "StartNaam" :(

Comment: @Nathan: Can you write a Java class whose main method immediately starts with a `return;` statement, followed by some other, unreachable statement (for example, `System.out.println("Hello World");`)? Eclipse won't compile it (that is, Eclipse doesn't made any exception for main methods). I'm curious to know what compiler you're using and if that compiler makes the exception you speak of.

Comment: Eclipse Version: Helios Service Release 1
Build id: 20100917-0705

Comment: @Menno: Will your version of Eclipse compile this code? http://pastebin.com/XEH9fufR

Comment: @Adam, no it says Unreachable code for the line "System.out.println("Hello World");"

Comment: @Menno: Your results suggest that this answer's explanation is incorrect (for Eclipse compilers, at least). I am still curious to know which Nathan has observed this behavior on... Regardless, once you post the *exact* version of the code that's experiencing the problem, we can form a better explanation.

Comment: @Adam; added it to the first post, at the end.

Answer (score 0):

On this line you use 1 instead of i:

```
xmlGrabber.NAME = nodes.item(1).getNodeValue();
```

That probably explains the compiler warning and why printing to the console works but retrieving the nodes doesn't.

Comment: That line works fine, Ventral. It simply gets the first value from the nodelist. It's the same as "String NAME = nodes.item(1).getNodeValue();" btw. It works fine within the method, but does nothing outside of it.

Comment: Ah ok, thought there might be some extra code you'd missed out as it's in a loop